# Error somewhere in my RNG for Monte-Carlo Simulation?

Tags: python, numpy, random, montecarlo, quantitative-finance

So, for a Monte-Carlo class, I created a uniform random number generator to simulate a normal distribution and use it for MC option pricing, and I'm going terribly wrong somewhere. It uses a simple *linear congruential generator* (lcg) which generates a random vector that is fed into an numerical approximation of a *inverse normal distribution* (beasley-springer-morrow algorithm) to generate standard normally distributed values (elaboration on the exact process can be found [here](http://www.quantopia.net/inverse-normal-cdf/)).

This is my code so far.

Rng:

```
def lcrm_generator(num, a, seed, c):

    mod = 4294967296 # 2^32
    val = int(seed)  #int() is to ensure seeds with a leading zero still get accepted by the program
    rng = []
    for i in range(num):
        val = (a * val + c) % mod
        rng.append(val/(mod-1))

    return rng
```

Inverse normal approximator:

```
def bsm_algorithm(u):

    # These are my necessary initial constants
    a0 = 2.50662823884; a1 = -18.61500062529; a2 = 41.39119773534; a3 = -25.44106049637;

    b0 = -8.47351093090; b1 = 23.08336743743; b2 = -21.06224101826; b3 = 3.13082909833;

    c0 = 0.3374754822726147; c1 = 0.9761690190917186; c2 = 0.1607979714918209; c3 = 0.0276438810333863;
    c4 = 0.0038405729373609; c5 = 0.0003951896511919; c6 = 0.0000321767881768; c7 = 0.0000002888167364;
    c8 = 0.0000003960315187;

    x = [0]*len(u)
    for i in range(len(u)):
        y = u[i] - 0.5
        if abs(y) < 0.42:
            r = y**2
            x[i] = y*(((a3*r+a2)*r+a1)*r+a0)/((((b3*r+b2)*r+b1)*r+b0)*r+1)
        else:
            r = u[i]
            if y > 0:
                r = 1 - u[i]
            r = log(-log(r))
            x[i] = c0+r*(c1+r*(c2+r*(c3+r*(c4+r*(c5+r*(c6+r*(c7+r*c8)))))))
            if y < 0:
                x[i] = -x[i]

    return x
```

Combining these two with the following and drawing the histogram shows the data looks correctly normal,

```
a=lcrm_generator(100000,301,"0",21)
b = bsm_algorithm(a)
plt.hist(b, bins=100)
plt.show()
```

[image: hist]

And option pricing function:

```
def LookbackOP(S,K,r,sigma,intervals,sims,Call_Put=1):

    ## My objects that will determine the option prices.
    path = [0]*intervals
    values = [0]*sims

    ## Objects to hold the random nums used for simulation.
    randuni = [0]*sims
    randnorm = [0]*sims
    for i in range(sims):
        randuni[i] = lcrm_generator(intervals,301,i,21)
        randnorm[i] = bsm_algorithm(randuni[i]) 

    # Generating the simulation one by one.
    for i in range(sims):
        path[0] = 1

        ## Below is to generate one whole simulated path.

        ################## MY INCORRECT WAY ##################
        for j in range(1,intervals):
            path[j] = path[j-1]*exp((r - .5*sigma**2)*(1/intervals) + sqrt(1/intervals)*randnorm[i][j])

        ################## CORRECT BUILT-IN WAY ##################
            # path[j] = path[j-1]*exp((r - .5*sigma**2)*(1/intervals) + sqrt(1/intervals)*np.random.normal(0,1))

        ## For each separate simulation, price the option either as a call or a put.    
        if Call_Put == 1:
            values[i] = max(S*max(path)-K,0)
        elif Call_Put == 0:
            values[i] = max(K-S*min(path),0)
        else:
            print("Error: You inputted something other than '1 = Call', or '0 = Put'")
    plt.hist(values,bins=30)
    plt.show()

    ## To get expected return of option by takeing their avg.
    option_value = np.mean(values)
    print(option_value)
    return option_value
```

In the last block of code, my error is pointed out, which seemingly can be fixed by simply using **numpy's** normal rng. Using one versus the other produces drastically different answers, and I'm tempted to trust **numpy** over myself, but my code looks normal, so where am I going wrong.

Comment: I did some visual comparison between your pseudorandom distribution and the `numpy.randon.normal` and the latter one seemed a little bit pointier. Maybe they are not completely equal? I also tried generating numbers with `numpy.random.rand` and then used your `bsm_algorithm` to get a normal distribution. It looked more like the `numpy.random.normal` one, which makes me suspect that your rng is not having a correct, uniform distribution. Since I know nothing of MC option pricing, I cannot say anything about the final results.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of, that somehow the data was subtly non-normal. I guess I have to read up more on the math of choosing the right constants for the lcg rng, as I have heard you need to pick the right constants to make it work, but never believed it would have mush affect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,

```
a=lcrm_generator(100000,301,"0",21)
```

this looks weird - why do you need a character for seed? Anyway, good parameters are in the table here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator. But problem is not LCG, I believe, but there might be systemic difference in your gaussian.

I ran code

```
from scipy.stats import norm
q = lcrm_generator(100000, 301, "0", 21)
g = bsm(q)

param = norm.fit(g)
print(param)
```

for 100 000, 1 000 000 and 10 000 000 samples, and my output is

```
(0.0009370998731855792, 0.9982155665317061)
(-0.0006429485100838258, 0.9996875045073682)
(-0.0007464875819397183, 1.0002711142625116)
```

and there is no improvement between 1 000 000 and 10 000 000 samples. Basically, you use some approximation for gaussian inverse function, and those are just artifacts of approximation, nothing to be done about it.

Numpy, I believe, is using one of the precise normal sampling methods (Box-Muller, I think)

Comment: I just reran the same test as you, except using `np.random.normal(0,1)`, and the parameters became predictably more precise as the sample increased so this must just be an issue with the BSM algorithm. This was giving me quite some anxiety, thank you for showing me how I should have tested my code for where the problem could be.

Comment: @Coolio2654 U're welcome. A lot more tests are here (Komogorov-Smirnov etc) in SciPy and Statsmodels